# How to Add Custom Fields on JoeBlogs Wordpress Wrapper

Tags: c#, wordpress, wrapper, xml-rpc, joeblogs

I'm trying to complete fields with JoeBlogs WordPress Wrapper.

My code is:

```
private void postToWordpress(string title, string postContent,string tags, string aioTitle)
{       
    string link = this.maskedTextBox1.Text;
    string username = this.maskedTextBox2.Text;
    string password = this.maskedTextBox3.Text;

    var wp = new WordPressWrapper(link + "/xmlrpc.php", username, password);
    var post = new Post();

    post.Title = title;
    post.Body = postContent;
    post.Tags = tags.Split(',');

    string[] cf = new CustomField(); //{ ID = "name", Key = "aiosp_title", Value = "All in One SEO Title" };
    cf.ID = "name";
    cf.Key = "aiosp_title";
    cf.Value = "All in One SEO Title";

    post.CustomFields[0] = cf;

    wp.NewPost(post, false);
}
```

The error is at this line:

```
post.CustomFields[0] = cf;
```

And it is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in JoeBlogsWordpressWrapperTests.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

So, how to use/add correctly custom fields on WordPress from C# Application using JoeBlogs WordPress Wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code fixes your `NullReferenceException` and also successfully saves the custom fields into the `Post` in Wordpress.

```
private void postToWordpress(string title, string postContent,string tags, string aioTitle)
{       
    string link = this.maskedTextBox1.Text;
    string username = this.maskedTextBox2.Text;
    string password = this.maskedTextBox3.Text;

    var wp = new WordPressWrapper(link + "/xmlrpc.php", username, password);
    var post = new Post();

    post.Title = title;
    post.Body = postContent;
    post.Tags = tags.Split(',');

    var cfs = new CustomField[] 
        { 
            new CustomField() 
            { 
                // Don't pass in ID. It's auto assigned for new custom fields.
                // ID = "name", 
                Key = "aiosp_title", 
                Value = "All in One SEO Title" 
            } 
        };

    post.CustomFields = cfs;

    wp.NewPost(post, false);
}
```

You were getting the `NullReferenceException` error because you were creating a `string` array and trying to assign it the `CustomFields` property of the `Post` object, which is an array of `CustomField` i.e. `CustomField[]`.

Also, in order to save the `CustomFields` to the `Post` in the database, you should pass in only the `Key` and `Value` fields of the `CustomField` `struct` and skip the `ID` field all together. Reason being Wordpress auto-generates the `ID` fields (also it's an `integer` / numeric field in the database). I think that was what was causing the `XmlRpc` call to fail, but we did not get any errors as to why.

Try the above code and it should work (I have it working on my localhost WAMP Wordpress installation).

One final note. Although the `CustomField`'s name property is called `Key`, it doesn't have to be unique, and uniqueness is not enforced. So for instance, if you are populating a custom dropdown box with a `list of cities` for a `Post`, you could have the `list of cities` as a set of custom fields as follows.

```
    var cfs = new CustomField[] 
        { 
            new CustomField() 
            { 
                Key = "aiosp_title", 
                Value = "All in One SEO Title" 
            } , 
            new CustomField() 
            { 
                Key = "this is another custom field with HTML", 
                Value = "All in One SEO Title <br/> Keyword 1 <br/><p>This is some more text and html</p>" 
            } ,
            new CustomField() 
            { 
                Key = "list_of_cities", 
                Value = "San Francisco" 
            } ,
            new CustomField() 
            { 
                Key = "list_of_cities", 
                Value = "New York" 
            } 
        };
```

This will also get saved to the post, with 2 custom fields with the same `Key` value and different text in the `Value` field's value.

And last but not least, you can store HTML also in the custom fields (as shown above).

Comment: Actually it was implemented, read here: https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs/pull/18

Comment: Correct. I've updated my answer after doing a series of trial and error to figure out why your code was failing to save the custom fields. See updated answer above :)

Comment: Did you have any idea about these two cases: If i set Key = "aiosp_title" is working great and I can find in database the value after sending post, but if I try to insert Key = "_aiosp_title" it is not inserted in database, what's wrong with _, why isn't it submitted to database ?

Comment: Are you saying you have a leading space in the `Key` field? That should work. I was able to add a key with several spaces (as shown in code above).

Comment: I want to add underscore before name, and looks like: Key = "_aiosp_title" , but it don't want to get in database.

Comment: oh ok. I'll check on that (i.e. test it) later today and let you know what's going on.

Comment: I just found this bug report from 3 years ago, and it specifically mentions the plugin you are using. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17850 According to the log, this issue with `_` prefixed custom fields failing quietly via the XML-RPC API was fixed, but it looks like you are still experiencing it.